# how can ı change scrollbar color according to the user's choice?

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js, sass

I can change the scrollbar specific color being red as follows but I want to change the scroll color based on the color variable I get from the user.

I think I can solve this solution in two ways.

1. I need to give variable to the 15th line. (instead of a specific color like red ) Is this possible ?

Or

2. I need to handle scrollbar being div element then I can change scrollbar color in ts file. But how can I catch scrollbar in dom ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [There must be a dupe here](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+OR+CSS+change+scrollbar+color+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Have you investigated setting and using CSS variables? Also, please put your code into your question, not an image of it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check about css variables https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple, you can try in this way.
you can include a color input element in your html and set the background color of the scroll bar to its value.

```js
var colorInput = document.getElementById("color-input");
var root = document.querySelector(":root");

colorInput.onchange = function() {

  root.style.setProperty("--scrollbar-color", colorInput.value);

}
```

```css
:root {

  --scrollbar-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); /* red */

}
div {

  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar {

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: lightgrey;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

  background-color: var(--scrollbar-color);

}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color-input">
<div>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
</div>
```

so now when the user selects a color, it is getting applied to the scrollbar. try it using the **run code snippet** button

**Edit :-**

as you have commented, it can be did specifically like this, just a simple change

see the edited code here.

```js
var colorInput = document.getElementById("color-input");
var element = document.getElementById("el");

colorInput.onchange = function() {

  el.style.setProperty("--scrollbar-color", colorInput.value);

}
```

```css
#el {

  --scrollbar-color : rgb(255, 0, 0) /* red */
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}

#el::-webkit-scrollbar {

  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: lightgrey;

}

#el::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {

  background-color: var(--scrollbar-color);

}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color-input">
<div id="el">
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
text<br>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks a lot. I want to ask something for understanding more clearly. Why did we use ':root' being querySelector? When ı use being ':root' I capture the whole page. Couldn't we have handled it more specifically instead of the whole page?

Comment: yes for sure! I just did this for example, see the edited code. I jchanged the javascript variable to refer to the div element instead of referring the root, and added the css variable in the div element instead of the root.

Answer (score 0):

#### In your CSS

```
--scrollbarBG: red;
--thumbBG: blue;

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 11px;
}
body {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: var(--thumbBG) var(--scrollbarBG);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--scrollbarBG);
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--thumbBG);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid var(--scrollbarBG);
}
```